# Geolocation Error When Trying to Save a New Record

Tags: json, laravel, algolia

I'm using algolia with laravel for my searching.  That's working fine, but when I added geolocation, I ran into a problem. I have fields in the db for lat and lng so added this into the model:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $record = $this->toArray();

        $record['_geoloc'] = [
            'lat' => $record['latitude'],
            'lng' => $record['longitude'],
        ];

        unset($record['created_at'], $record['updated_at']); // Remove unrelevant data
        unset($record['latitude'], $record['longitude']);

        return $record;
    }
```

However, when I tried to save a model, I got this error:

> _geoloc.lat or _geoloc.lng attributes cannot be null near line:1      > column:526

So I then I added a '_geoloc field to the db, which was a TEXT.
But now, I'm getting this error when trying to save my model:

> AlgoliaSearch \ AlgoliaException (400)
>   _geoloc attribute cannot contains a string near line:1 column:606

From the error message:

> $answer = Json::decode($response, true);
>
> ```
>    if (intval($http_status / 100) == 4) {
>        throw new AlgoliaException(isset($answer['message']) ?     > $answer['message'] : $http_status.' error', $http_status);
> ```

Here's the saving of the model:

```
        //gets an array of lat and lng
        //$gps is an assoc array
        //logger($geoJson) yields {"lat":34.8802845,"lng":-77.1041536}
        $gps = Map::getListingDetails($request);
        $geoJson = json_encode($gps);

        $listing = Listing::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                '_geoloc' => $gps,               
         ]);
```

Am I doing something wrong from the beginning, or at the end?  With the toSearchAbleArray, shouldn't the algolia code be able to decode the json string saved in the db?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find a resolution yet? Working on this same problem for a while now. Tried everything under the sun in storing the record in the database - nothing works.

Comment: I am having the same error. I have opened an issue for this with AlgoliaSearch on github. https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php/issues/554

Answer (score 1):

Your use of

```php
toSearchableArray
```

is the write way to do this but the associative array keys in the model/controller are not matching. In the controller you are using "lat" and "lng" but in the model you are using "latitude" and "longitude".

In your model change:

```php
'lat' => $record['latitude'],
'lng' => $record['longitude'],
```

to:

```php
'lat' => $record['lat'],
'lat' => $record['lng'],
```

You will not be able to store an associative array in MySQL. I suggest changing:

```php
$gps = Map::getListingDetails($request);
```

to

```php
$input = Map::getListingDetails($request)
$gps = serialize($input);
```

- [Algolia Geo Location Documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/)
- [Aloglia Airport Demo](https://preview.algolia.com/geo-search/)
- [Julien Bourdeau, software engineer from Algolia, Geo Search article.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/achieving-geo-search-with-laravel-scout-and-algolia)
- [Github algolia/algoliasearch-client-php Issue #554](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php/issues/554)